# Change QApplication stylefile dynamically

Tags: c++, qt

So I have two qss files which contain the stylesheet of all the buttons backgrounds
One file for normal mode and the other for darkmode, the only difference between the two files are color choices.
**StyleFile.qss** and **DarkStyleFile.qss**

Before when I had just one qss, I used to set it to the app like so:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
           QFile  stylesheet_file(":/Images/Resources/StyleFile.qss");
           stylesheet_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
           QString stylesheet = QLatin1String(stylesheet_file.readAll());
           app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet);
    w.show();    
    return app.exec();
}
```

Now that I have two qss files, I want to be able to switch between them on a button click in the app, say I have a checkbox or togglebutton with the name "darkmode" and once its checked in changes the path to: **":/Images/Resources/DarkStyleFile.qss"**

This is my first attempt:

```
//mainwindow.cpp with QPushbutton set as checkable named toggle

void MainWindow::on_toggle_clicked()
{
    QApplication *app= (QApplication*)QApplication::instance();
    app->processEvents();
    QFile  stylesheet_file(":/Images/Resources/StyleFile.qss");
    if(ui->toggle->isChecked()){
    QFile  stylesheet_file(":/Images/Resources/DarkStyleFile.qss");
    }
    stylesheet_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString stylesheet = QLatin1String(stylesheet_file.readAll());
    app->setStyleSheet(stylesheet);
}
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//create application and main window
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w; 
    w.show();    
    return app.exec();
}
```

This didn't work at all, it showed me the default qt button designs with no background so I tried something else

This is my second attempt:
**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "admininterface.h"
#include "employeeinterface.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    QString on_toggle_clicked();
private slots:
    void on_Exit_clicked();
    void on_Login_clicked();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    AdminInterface *Admin;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
QString MainWindow::on_toggle_clicked()
{
    QFile  stylesheet_file(":/Images/Resources/StyleFile.qss");
    if(ui->toggle->isChecked()){
    QFile  stylesheet_file(":/Images/Resources/DarkStyleFile.qss");
    }
    stylesheet_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString stylesheet = QLatin1String(stylesheet_file.readAll());
    return stylesheet;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//create application and main window
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    app.setStyleSheet(w.on_toggle_clicked());
    w.show();    
    return app.exec();
}
```

When I run the app now, it is set up with the normal stylesheet **StyleFile.qss** but nothing really happens when I click on the button that is meant to change the path, I don't know if its because the stylefile is only set up at the start of the application and can't be changed while running, do i need to update something or if I did something wrong, I want to be able to change stylesheet from light to dark mode while in the app at anytime the user hits the button, what did I do wrong? Or is there a much easier way to do it please let me know, and if something is still not clear or I gave not enough information please comment and let me know i'll fix asap.

Comment: Your `stylesheet_file` variable within the `if(ui->toggle->isChecked()) {` conditional shadows the variable of the same name defined immediately before the conditional and is, therefore, never used.

Comment: I've been working on it a few days and I think I know that its impossible to do this way, since the int main() doesn't update, i've been thinking to call QApplication in mainwindow but I couldn't do that since only one QApp is allowed which already is in the main, also I've read stuff about threading and all which seamed to complicated for a simple task like this

Answer (score 1):

Consider your `MainWindow::on_toggle_clicked` implementation...

```
QString MainWindow::on_toggle_clicked()
{
    QFile  stylesheet_file(":/Images/Resources/StyleFile.qss"); // (1)
    if(ui->toggle->isChecked()){
        QFile  stylesheet_file(":/Images/Resources/DarkStyleFile.qss"); // (2)
    }
    stylesheet_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString stylesheet = QLatin1String(stylesheet_file.readAll());
    return stylesheet;
}
```

The `stylesheet_file` variable defined at (1) is completely separate/distict from the `stylesheet_file` variable defined at (2).  Rather than defining a new variable with the same name at (2) you should set the file name associated with the previously defined variable using...

```
stylesheet_file.setFileName(":/Images/Resources/DarkStyleFile.qss");
```

So the resulting implementation would look something like...

```
QString MainWindow::on_toggle_clicked ()
{
    QFile  stylesheet_file(":/Images/Resources/StyleFile.qss");
    if (ui->toggle->isChecked()){
        stylesheet_file.setFileName(":/Images/Resources/DarkStyleFile.qss");
    }
    stylesheet_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString stylesheet = QLatin1String(stylesheet_file.readAll());
    return stylesheet;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, although its a lot cleaner, but it doesn't seam to be the problem, still its only showing the stylesheet **:/Images/Resources/StyleFile.qss** but pushing the button won't change it, I'm pretty sure the problem is that main doesn't update by itself